# Possible to Directly access related records (Laravel ORM style)?

Tags: plugin-development

This post may scream ignorance (Still delving into the plugin world). I'm coming from a background using mostly laravel for PHP application development and building a few plugins now on Craft has felt a bit verbose to access related objects. Is there any "nice" way to allow something like the following in Craft?

```
$phone = User::find(1)->phone;
```

or in terms of craft plugins, just include related data in the model itself instead of having dozens of findXbyId methods littering the code?

related: [populateModel usage with eager loading related records](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/7077/populatemodel-usage-with-eager-loading-related-records)

Any generic solutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure I'm following what you're looking for, but if you have a `UserRecord` defined with a `phone` relation, then something like this should do what you want:

```
$phone = UserRecord::model()->with('phone')->findById(1)->phone;
```

Comment: I suppose that will do, I was trying to find a way to somewhat automate it but it might just be overkill. What would be the syntax to call an extra relation? 
```$phone = UserRecord::model()->with('phone, age')->findById(1)->phone;```

Comment: Got it. ```$phone = UserRecord::model()->with('phone', 'age')->findById(1)->phone;```